# This loading plist is wrong?

Tags: objective-c, plist

```
NSString *levelPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level%d", level] ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *levelData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:levelPlist];
```

When I load plist like this, `levelPlist` is just a *(null)*.
`stringWithFormat`syntax is wrong?

Comment: how could we know what the current name of your file in `Documents` folder... oopsy-daisy... if the file is in your `Documents` folder, that is not part of the bundle, so the path (or URL) will be `nil` always from `mainBundle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always when debugging break the problem down,first get the file name, then loading the file contents.

Then `NSLog()` the file name and verify that a file with that name exists directly in the app bundle. Do that by actually looking in the app file.

Safe bet: It the file with the formatted names and extension does not exist directly in the app bundle.

Possibilities:

1. The file you are trying to read exists in the app's Documents directory.
2. The file name is not what you think.
3. There is a case difference, iOS has a case sensitive file system, that is different than OSX.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it. The problem is the 'level'integer.
'level'value is 01, but compiler understand it 1 not 01.
So my path was (null).